# How to order my dataframe lexicographicaly

Tags: r, sorting, r-faq

I have a following data frame

```
a = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),b=c(1,2,3,10,12,21,4),c=c(1,2,10,11,"X","Y",3))
> a
  a  b  c
1 1  1  1
2 2  2  2
3 3  3 10
4 4 10 11
5 5 12  X
6 6 21  Y
7 7  4  3
```

I want to sort whole data frame in lexicographical order, so that the output (for example, column "c") should be like

```
> a[,"c"]
[1] 1  2  3 10 11  X  Y
```

I tried and I am geting different answer

```
indata <- a[do.call(order,a[,c("c","a","b")]),]
> indata[,"c"]
[1] 1  10 11 2  3  X  Y
Levels: 1 10 11 2 3 X Y
```

I tried gtools, mixedorder package and worked fine on one column:

```
> a[mixedorder(a$c),]
  a  b  c
1 1  1  1
2 2  2  2
3 3  3 10
4 4 10 11
5 5 12  X
6 6 21  Y
7 7  4  3
```

but it doesn't work if I include multiple columns:

```
> a[with(a,order(mixedorder(c),mixedorder(b),mixedorder(a))),]
  a  b  c
1 1  1  1
2 2  2  2
4 4 10 11
5 5 12  X
6 6 21  Y
7 7  4  3
3 3  3 10
```

though I am expecting :

```
  a  b  c
1 1  1  1
2 2  2  2
4 7  4  3
5 3  3 10
6 4 10 11
7 5 12  X
3 6 21  Y
```

Comment: You'll have to be more clear. Do you want to sort just column `c`, or the whole data frame with respect to columns `c`?

Comment: I want to sort  whole data frame with respect to c. I gave a[,"c"] for easy understanding

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19014531/680068

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to use `mixedorder()` from the **gtools** package.

```
library(gtools)
a[mixedorder(a$c),]
#   a  b  c
# 1 1  1  1
# 2 2  2  2
# 7 7  4  3
# 3 3  3 10
# 4 4 10 11
# 5 5 12  X
# 6 6 21  Y
```

Comment: How would I use multiple columns together for sorting (first c,then b and then a)?

Comment: @user1631306 Try `arrange` in the **plyr** package.

Comment: @user1631306 -- In that case, you could do this:  `a[with(a, order(mixedorder(c), b, a)),]`.

Answer (score 4):

Sticking in base you could make a function yourself:

```
a = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),b=c(1,2,3,10,12,21,4),c=c(1,2,10,11,"X","Y",3))

SORTER_DEVICE <- function(x) {
    c(sort(as.numeric(na.omit(gsub("[a-zA-Z]", NA, x)))),
        sort(na.omit(gsub("[0-9]", NA, x))))
}
data.frame(apply(a, 2, SORTER_DEVICE))
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately mixedsort does not (yet) support multiple column sorting. So, you need to implement it yourself, for example like this:

```r
a[order(sub("[0-9]+", "", a$c),
        as.numeric(sub("[[:alpha:]]*([[:digit:]]*)", '\\1', a$c)),
        as.numeric(a$b),
        as.numeric(a$a)), ]
```

This first, alphanumerically sorts data.frame using a$c, and for tie situations(which actually does not exist in your data.frame 'a'), it uses a$b and a$a.

Output is:

```
  a  b  c
1 1  1  1
2 2  2  2
7 7  4  3
3 3  3 10
4 4 10 11
5 5 12  X
6 6 21  Y
```

PS: This was written by David Winsemius in [this post](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/choosing-multiple-columns-tp4640025p4640104.html%20here) as a reply to a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are human chromosome names, *chr1...chr22, chrX, chrY*. We can convert them to numeric, then use order:

```
# convert to numeric
a$chromN <- as.integer(ifelse(a$c == "X", "23", ifelse(a$c == "Y", "24", a$c)))

# now sort as usual:
a[ order(a$chromN), ]

#   a  b  c chromN
# 1 1  1  1      1
# 3 3  3 10      2
# 4 4 10 11      3
# 2 2  2  2      4
# 7 7  4  3      5
# 5 5 12  X     23
# 6 6 21  Y     24
```