# sort by chromosome name

Tags: r, sorting

I have a vector of chromosome names

```
q<-c("1","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17",
     "18","19","20","21","22","2","3","4","5","6",
     "7","8","9","X","Y","M")
```

I want to sort them as

```
q<-c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11",
     "12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20",
     "21","22","X","Y","M")
```

I tried to make my own order

```
chrOrder <-c((1:22),"X","Y","M")
```

and use it like

```
factor(cbind(q),levels=chrOrder)
```

But still I couldnt get it.

Edited.....
I have similar senario but sligtly advanced. I have a data frame of three columns , name, chromosome, start

```
df <-data.frame(name =c("a","a","a","b","b","b"), chrom = c(1,2,10,1,3,"X"), start=c(100,200,300,500,300,200))
```

I need to sort it first by name, then chromosome and the start.
The result should be like

```
name chrom start
a     1   100
a     10  300
a     2   200
b     1   500
b     3   300
b     X   200
```

I dont know how to use chrOrder in following:

```
indata  <- df[do.call(order,df[,c(name, chrom, start)]),];
```

Comment: Why not use `chrOrder` directly? Why do you expect that `factor` sorts your vector? Likewise, `cbind` has no effect here.

Comment: I'm confused by the edited question's desired result. Is it a mistake that the third row is not before the second row?

Comment: Its sorted by first "name", then "chrom". where the sorting of number is not in natural way. Its like 1,10,100,2,200,22,299,300

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12806128/680068

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is good; you just need to `sort` the resulting factor. You should also set `ordered=TRUE`:

```
sort(factor(q,levels=chrOrder, ordered=TRUE))
```

No, you don't have to use an ordered factor, as has been pointed out, but it's certainly not wrong--and it's arguably better. Factors are for this type of situation, where you have well-defined levels. See [this previous question on on `factor` vs `character`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445316/factors-in-r-more-than-an-annoyance).

Now that you've edited your question, the case for a factor is even stronger because sorting is simple:

```
df <- data.frame(name=c("a","a","a","b","b","b"),
                 chrom = c(1,2,10,1,3,"X"),
                 start=c(100,200,300,500,300,200))

chrOrder <-c((1:22),"X","Y","M")
df$chrom <- factor(df$chrom, chrOrder, ordered=TRUE)

df[do.call(order, df[, c("name", "chrom", "start")]), ]
```

Given the levels of the factor, R knows exactly how to sort the elements.

I've followed your lead with the sorting method, but you might like to know that there are prettier ways, e.g.:

```
library(plyr)
df <- arrange(df, name, chrom, start)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have additional problem that I have edited in the question

Comment: You just need to re-assign your `chrom` column as a factor with the ordered levels.

Answer (score 3):

`factor` and `cbind` don’t do anything here (well, `factor` does, but it’s not immediately useful).

In your specific case, just saying `q <- chrOrder` solves the problem, doesn’t it?

More generally, you can use [`match`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) to get the indices of items in a vector `x` ordered by the items in another vector `y`:

```
> match(chrOrder, q)
 [1]  1 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 23 24 25
```

Now you can use those indices to index into `q` and get it ordered:

```
> q[match(chrOrder, q)]
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15"
[16] "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" "21" "22" "X"  "Y"  "M"
```

… so this is the general approach. For instance, as a more useful example: assuming that you actually have a `data.frame` of genes with a `chr` column, you could order the rows of the data frame as follows:

```
> # Some test data
> df <- data.frame(chr = q, value = rnbinom(length(q), 1, 0.01),
+                  row.names = paste('gene', seq_along(q)))
> df <- df[match(chrOrder, df$chr), ]
> head(df)
        chr value
gene 1    1   270
gene 15   2    51
gene 16   3   115
gene 17   4    15
gene 18   5   196
gene 19   6    34
```

… the data frame columns are now ordered by its `chr` column in the order you desired.