# Sort chromosome names using factor

Tags: r, sorting, na

I have two dataframes, each with two columns - the chromosome name and the counts of that chromosome which I want to plot chronologically. However, I have problems if some chromosomes aren't counted at all. Below is a small sample of my data:

```r
df1$chrom
chr1 chr10 chr3 chr4 chr5
df1$count
1 2 1 4 5
```

and

```r
df2$chrom
chr1 chr10 chr3 chr5
df2$count
1 4 3 1
```

To order them chronologically I'm using factor

```r
chrOrder <-c(paste0("chr",1:22),"chrX","chrY")
df1$chrom <- factor(df2_8$Chromosome, chrOrder, ordered=TRUE)
df1<- df1[do.call(order, df1[, c("chrom ", "count")]), ]
```

which for df1 gives me

```r
df1$chrom
chr1 chr3 chr4 chr5 chr10
df1$count
1 1 4 5 2
```

And it also works for the second dataframe.

But in order to plot them effectively I need the second dataframe to contain a 0 for chromosome 4 which hasn't been counted in this data.

```r
df2$chrom
chr1 chr3 chr4 chr5 chr10
df2$count
1 3 0 1 4
```

I've tried when using factor to add NA and then replace it with 0, using `addNA` but it doesnt work. Could anyone help me? Thank you.

My question is similar to [sort by chromosome name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014531/sort-by-chromosome-name) but I'm not sure how to solve the specific part of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `tidyr::complete` to get missing  `chrom` values from `df1`

```
df3 <- tidyr::complete(df2, chrom = factor(chrom, levels = levels(df1$chrom)), 
                fill = list(count = 0))

# chrom count
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 chr1      1
#2 chr10     4
#3 chr3      3
#4 chr4      0
#5 chr5      1
```

To sort them we could use `gtools::mixedorder`

```
df3[gtools::mixedorder(df3$chrom), ]

# chrom count
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 chr1      1
#2 chr3      3
#3 chr4      0
#4 chr5      1
#5 chr10     4
```

Or make something custom

```
df3[order(as.integer(gsub("[^0-9]", "", df3$chrom))), ]
```